# can session with context manager replace scoped_session in threaded situations

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy suggests the transaction pattern for sessions:

```
# myapp.py
from contextlib import contextmanager

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
...
with session_scope() as session:
   # do stuff
```

Furthermore, I have noticed that for web applications, `session_scope` should be used:

```
# my_scoped_app.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db')
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

...
# Some app definition
...


@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()
```

Since I want to scale Flask beyond a single-thread, is it safe to use the first pattern?  In other words, does it matter whether I implement some class like

```
from myapp import session_scope()

class Foo(object):
   def do_stuff(self, args):
      with session_scope() as session:
          do_more_stuff(session, args)
```

versus

```
from my_scoped_app import db_session:

class Foo(object):
   def do_stuff(self, args):
      session = db_session()
      do_more_stuff(session, args)
      session.commit()
      session.close()
```

Ignoring the differences in exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

What i found is that the first approach will create new session each time you call it. The second approach will firstly check if session for current thread exists and if not will also create new session.
Second approach is alot cleaner when dealing with session in different modules within same thread.
So technicly you're getting the same from both within single request while using it.

Comment: I consider this an acceptable partial answer, i.e. appreciated participation in the answering process while no full answer exists yet. But please phrase posts like this more carefully to aovid the impression of asking a question or saying "me too". The impression of being a text wall can be avoided with the help of this info: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help